# How can i merge disk 0 and disk 1 | Windows

Tags: windows, partitioning, windows-server-2012

I shrinked my disk 0 and i tried to expand my disk1 but unlocated space doesn't seen on expand option. How can i merge different disks ?

[image]

Comment: You cannot merge 2 different disks. The only options you have here are to make a new partition for the unallocated space OR to expand your C:\ to use the whole space. If you wanted to combine both disks, you would have to wipe your whole machine and reinstall the disks in a `raid 0` configuration.

Comment: It's better to buy a bigger disk that is more than you need, instead of using disk spanning.  Disk spanning is slower and much less reliable than just buying a 4 TB or larger disk.

Comment: @Narzard should be an answer not a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you *can* do what you want, using [Dynamic Disks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363785(v=vs.85).aspx#dynamic_disks). Dynamic Disks are much like LVM on Linux, except it’s a proprietary Microsoft technology.

Using Dynamic Disks will *seriously* impair your ability to use arbitrary software for backup and partition management. Converting a drive is also non-reversible (at least not officially) without removing *all* data from a drive.

***As such I must very much advise against using Dynamic Disks.***

If you’re sure you want to proceed, just right-click on the drive area (to the left) in Disk Management and select the conversion option. Convert both drives. You can then extend your volume `D:` with the free space on drive 0.

Again: Make very sure you want this. Going back is a major PITA.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot merge 2 different disks. The only options you have here are to make a new partition for the unallocated space OR to expand your C:\ to use the whole space. If you wanted to combine both disks, you would have to wipe your whole machine and reinstall the disks in a `raid 0` configuration